# How would I get a certain integer from a string within a list?

Tags: c#, string, list

I currently have a large list:

```
string[,] list = {{"371072875339021","0279","8797998220837590246510135740250"},
                 { "463769376774900","0971","2648124896970078050417018260538"},
                 { "743249861995247","4105","9474233309513058123726617309629"},
                 { "919422133635741","6157","2522430563301811072406154908250"},
                 { "230675882075393","4617","1171980310421047513778063246676"}, etc.
```

I'm trying to find a certain integer from a certain string from within the list, any help would be great as I'm struggling to find a way to get the exact character from the preferred string.(Length of the string doesn't matter, just looking for a particular one e.g. list[1,2] then the 4th number in the string).

Comment: I specified it a bit more, sorry. I'm basically just trying to get a desired integer from one of the strings from the list.

Answer (score 1):

> list[1,2] then the 4th number in the string

You can look up characters in a string by index, just like an array, so you can do this:

```
char result = list[1,2][3];
```

Note: `[3]` rather than `[4]` for the fourth character because it's 0-indexed.

If you want the integer value of the digit:

```
int result = list[1,2][3] - '0';
```

For the sample data in the question, the result is:

---

## 8

---